# Quarkus persistence exception and java null pointer exception

Tags: java, quarkus

End point class:

```
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class UserEndPoint {

        @Inject
        private UserRepository UserDao;

        @GET
        @Path("user")
        public List<Utilisateur> all() {
            return UserDao.findAllUsers();
        }

        @GET
        @Path("user/by-name")
        public List<Utilisateur> findByName(@PathParam String name, @PathParam String firstName) {
            return UserDao.findbyName(name, firstName);
        }

        @GET
        @Path("user/create-after")
        public List<Utilisateur> findCreateAfter(@PathParam Date date) {
            return UserDao.findByCreate_Date(date);
        }

        @GET
        @Path("User/{userId}")
        public Utilisateur findById(@PathParam Long id) {
            Utilisateur p = UserDao.findById(id);
            if (p == null)
                throw new WebApplicationException(Status.NOT_FOUND);
            return p;
        }

        @PUT
        @Path("User/{userId}")
        public void updateUser(@PathParam Long id, Utilisateur newUser) {
            Utilisateur p = UserDao.findById(id);
            if (p == null)
                throw new WebApplicationException(Status.NOT_FOUND);
            p.setBirth_date(newUser.getBirth_date());
            p.setFirtName(newUser.getFirtName());
            p.setLastname(newUser.getLastname());
        }

        @DELETE
        @Path("User/{userId}")
        public void deleteUser(@PathParam Long id) {
            Utilisateur p = UserDao.findById(id);
            if (p == null)
                throw new WebApplicationException(Status.NOT_FOUND);
            UserDao.delete(p);
        }

        @POST
        @Path("user")
        public Response newUser(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, Utilisateur newUser) {
            Utilisateur p = new Utilisateur();
            p.setBirth_date(newUser.getBirth_date());
            p.setFirtName(newUser.getFirtName());
            p.setLastname(newUser.getLastname());
            UserDao.persist(p);

            URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(UserEndPoint.class).path(UserEndPoint.class, "findById")
                    .build(p.getUserId());
            return Response.created(uri).build();
        }

    }
```

Dao classs:

```
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class UserRepository implements PanacheRepository<Utilisateur> {

        @Inject
        protected EntityManager entityManager;

        @Transactional
        public List<Utilisateur> findbyName(String lastname, String firstName) {

            List<Utilisateur> users = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                users = entityManager.createQuery("FROM User WHERE lastName = :lastName and firstName", Utilisateur.class)
                        .setParameter("lastName", lastname).getResultList();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            return users;

        }

        @Transactional
        public List<Utilisateur> findByCreate_Date(Date date) {

            List<Utilisateur> users = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                users = entityManager.createQuery("FROM User WHERE create_date> :date", Utilisateur.class)
                        .setParameter("date", date).getResultList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            return users;
        }

        @Transactional
        public void persist(Utilisateur person) {
            try {
                entityManager.persist(person);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

        @Transactional
        public void delete(Utilisateur person) {
            try {
                entityManager.remove(person);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

        @Transactional
        public Utilisateur findByUserId(Long id) {
            Utilisateur userid = null;
            try {
                userid = entityManager.find(Utilisateur.class, id);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            return userid;
        }

        @Transactional
        public List<Utilisateur> findAllUsers() {
            List<Utilisateur> users = new ArrayList<Utilisateur>();
            try {
                users = entityManager.createQuery("FROM User", Utilisateur.class).getResultList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            return users;
        }

    }
```

Entity class:

```
    @Slf4j
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Utilisateur")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
    @DiscriminatorValue("P_")
    @RegisterForReflection
    public class Utilisateur extends PanacheEntity implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 461991388948874292L;

        // ------------------------proprieties----------------------------------------
        Date date = null;
        protected static final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "USER_ID")
        protected Long userId;

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
        @Column(name = "firstName", length = 50)
        protected String firtName;

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
        @Column(name = "lastName", length = 50)
        protected String lastname;

        @Column(name = "userName", length = 50)
        protected String userName;

        @Column(name = "login", length = 20)
        protected String login;

        @Column(name = "password", length = 50)
        protected String password;

        @Column(name = "email")
        private String email;

        @Column
        private String confirm_pass;

        @Column
        private Long group_id;

        @Column(name = "photo")
        protected String photo;

        @Column(name = "sex", length = 1)
        protected String sex;

        @Column(name = "nationality", length = 50)
        protected String nationality;

        @Column
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
        protected Date birth_date;

        @Column
        protected boolean authenticated;

        @Column
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a z")
        protected Date create_date;

        @Column
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a z")
        protected Date modify_date;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<UserRole> roles;

        @Embedded
        @AttributeOverrides({

                @AttributeOverride(name = "phone", column = @Column(name = "P_phone", nullable = false, updatable = true)),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "homePhone", column = @Column(name = "P_homePhone", nullable = false, updatable = true)),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "country", column = @Column(name = "P_country", nullable = false, updatable = true)),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "city", column = @Column(name = "P_city", nullable = false, updatable = true)),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "street", column = @Column(name = "P_street", nullable = false, updatable = true)),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "zipCode", column = @Column(name = "P_zipCode", nullable = false, updatable = true)) })
        Adress adress;

        public Long getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(Long userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public String getFirtName() {
            return firtName;
        }

        public void setFirtName(String firtName) {
            this.firtName = firtName;
        }

        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }

        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }

        public String getLogin() {
            return login;
        }

        public void setLogin(String login) {
            this.login = login;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getPhoto() {
            return photo;
        }

        public void setPhoto(String photo) {
            this.photo = photo;
        }

        public String getSex() {
            return sex;
        }

        public void setSex(String sex) {
            this.sex = sex;
        }

        public String getNationality() {
            return nationality;
        }

        public void setNationality(String nationality) {
            this.nationality = nationality;
        }

        public Date getBirth_date() {
            return birth_date;
        }

        public void setBirth_date(Date birth_date) {
            simpleDateFormat.format(birth_date);
            this.birth_date = birth_date;
        }

        public boolean isAuthenticated() {
            return authenticated;
        }

        public void setAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) {
            this.authenticated = authenticated;
        }

        public Date getCreate_date() {
            return create_date;
        }

        public void setCreate_date(Date date) {

            simpleDateFormat.format(date);
            this.create_date = date;
        }

        public Date getModify_date() {
            return modify_date;
        }

        public void setModify_date(Date modify_date) {
            simpleDateFormat.format(modify_date);
            this.modify_date = modify_date;
        }

        public Adress getAdress() {
            return adress;
        }

        public void setAdress(Adress adress) {
            this.adress = adress;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public List<UserRole> getRoles() {
            return roles;
        }

        public void setRoles(List<UserRole> roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getConfirm_pass() {
            return confirm_pass;
        }

        public void setConfirm_pass(String confirm_pass) {
            this.confirm_pass = confirm_pass;
        }

        public Long getGroup_id() {
            return group_id;
        }

        public void setGroup_id(Long group_id) {
            this.group_id = group_id;
        }

        public Utilisateur() {
            super();

        }

        public Utilisateur(String userName) {
            super();
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public Utilisateur(String userName, String password) {
            super();
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Utilisateur(@NotNull @Size(min = 3, max = 50) String firtName,
                @NotNull @Size(min = 3, max = 50) String lastname, String userName, String login, String password,
                String email, String confirm_pass, Long group_id, String photo, String sex, String nationality,
                Date birth_date, boolean authenticated, Date create_date, Date modify_date, List<UserRole> roles,
                Adress adress) {
            super();
            this.firtName = firtName;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.login = login;
            this.password = password;
            this.email = email;
            this.confirm_pass = confirm_pass;
            this.group_id = group_id;
            this.photo = photo;
            this.sex = sex;
            this.nationality = nationality;
            this.birth_date = birth_date;
            this.authenticated = authenticated;
            this.create_date = create_date;
            this.modify_date = modify_date;
            this.roles = roles;
            this.adress = adress;
        }

    }
```

I launch my application in command line, I get this exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.persistenceException(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:113)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:67)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:54)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:109)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig.startAll(JPAConfig.java:57)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.HibernateOrmRecorder.startAllPersistenceUnits(HibernateOrmRecorder.java:77)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits37.deploy_0(HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits37.zig:70)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits37.deploy(HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits37.zig:36)
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.doStart(ApplicationImpl1.zig:145)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:94)
        at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:143)
        at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.doStart(DevModeMain.java:180)
        at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:94)
        at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.mapping.impl.HibernateOrmMetatadaContributor.configure(HibernateOrmMetatadaContributor.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.mapping.spi.AbstractPojoMappingInitiator.configure(AbstractPojoMappingInitiator.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.mapping.impl.HibernateOrmMappingInitiator.configure(HibernateOrmMappingInitiator.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.common.impl.SearchIntegrationBuilderImpl$MappingBuildingState.collect(SearchIntegrationBuilderImpl.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.common.impl.SearchIntegrationBuilderImpl.prepareBuild(SearchIntegrationBuilderImpl.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.bootstrap.impl.HibernateOrmIntegrationBooterImpl.doBootFirstPhase(HibernateOrmIntegrationBooterImpl.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.bootstrap.impl.HibernateOrmIntegrationBooterImpl.bootNow(HibernateOrmIntegrationBooterImpl.java:194)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.bootstrap.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:41)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:389)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:65)
```

Can you help me please to resolve this exception.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I've done it for you this time but, in the future, please format your exceptions just as you did with the code. It makes reading it much more bearable. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue in Hibernate Search but your entity doesn't look like it uses it. Do you have entities using Hibernate Search? Are you trying to initialize Hibernate Search yourself instead of letting Quarkus do it? Did you use the Quarkus Hibernate Search + Elasticsearch extension? Because just adding the Hibernate Search dependencies won't work: you need to use the extension.

A NPE is always a bug as you should at least have a more meaningful exception if there's something unsupported. So we need to get to the bottom of what creates this unexpected situation.

In any case, posting a full reproducer (i.e. the smallest app reproducing the issue) would probably help.

Comment: Yes I use hibernate search dependencies in the pom.xml. If i comment puis, my application start successful. Thanks you very much.

Comment: If you want to use Hibernate Search, you need to use the extension. See the documentation there: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-search-elasticsearch